# How can I show the cardinality of the set $A_m=\{\alpha\in\mathbb N_0^n: |\alpha|\leq m\}$ is $\#A_m=\binom{m+n}{m}$?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Let $\mathbb N_0=\mathbb N\cup \{0\}$. An element of $\mathbb N_0^n$ is called a **multi-index**. In $\mathbb N_0^n$ consider the set $$A_m=\{\alpha\in\mathbb N_0^n: |\alpha|\leq m\},$$ where $\displaystyle |\alpha|=\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i$, $\displaystyle\alpha=(\alpha_1, \ldots
, \alpha_n)$, is the **length** of $\alpha$. How can I show the cardinality of $A$ is given by: $$\#A_m=\binom{m+n}{m}?$$ I think I must use induction but for this I have to find a smart way to write $A_m$ from $A_{m-1}$ but I'm a bit loss with it.

It is clear, $$A_m=A_{m-1}\cup B,$$ where $B\subset \mathbb N_0^n$ is a set formed by multi-indices of the form $\alpha=\beta+\delta_j$ with $|\beta|=m-1$. The problem is that $\beta$ does not run all the multi-indices of length $m-1$. Any hints?

**Notation:** $\delta_j=(0, \ldots, 1, \ldots, 0)$ with $1$ on $j$-th position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define $A'_k=\{(a_1,\ldots,a_n): a_1+\cdots+a_n=k\}$. Then $$A_m=\bigsqcup_{k=0}^mA_k'$$

Can you calculate the cardinality of $A_k'$? Think about bins and balls.

**SPOILER**

You should get that $\# A_k'=\displaystyle  \binom{n+k-1}k$ so that $\# A_m = \displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^m \binom{n+k-1}k$. Now $$\binom{m+n}m=\binom{m+n-1}n+\binom{m+n-1}{n-1}$$ By induction on $m+n$,  $$\binom{m+n-1}n= \displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{m-1} \binom{n+k-1}k=\sum_{k=1}^m\binom{n+k-2}{k-1}$$ and $$\binom{m+n-1}{n-1}= \displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^m \binom{n+k-2}k$$

Adding gives what we wanted.

Comment: Very cool! Thanks =)

Comment: I conjecture the elements of $A_k^{'}$ form the non zero entries of an upper triangular matrix. But I didn't figure out yet the relation of the order of this matrix with $k$ and $n$. If I did that I could find easily $\#A_k^{'}$.

Comment: @PtF Note that an ordered solution $a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n=k$ corresponds to placing $k$ (indistinguishable) balls in $n$ (distinguishable) bins.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this analogy. For example, in $\mathbb N_0^3$ I could ask for those $\alpha=(\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3)$ such that $\alpha_1+\alpha_2+\alpha_3=2$. Those are (1, 1, 0), (1, 0, 1), (0, 1, 1), (2, 0, 0), (0, 2, 0), (0, 0, 2). All right, in the group (1, 1, 0), (1, 0, 1), (0, 1, 1) I'm setting the balls 1 into the boxes which are the entries of the vector, right? What about the other group (2, 0, 0), (0, 2, 0), (0, 0, 2)? Are the 0 also balls?

Comment: I guess I got it, I can put more than one ball in the same box, right?

Comment: Yes, or no balls at all. Such tuple corresponds to placing $a_i$  balls in bin $i$.

Comment: Now I finally understood, the problem is about combinations with repetitions..